# Determining whether the line $\frac{x-2}{2} =\frac{y+2}{-4} =\frac{z+3}{9}$ contains the point $(3,-4,1)$

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I determine whether the line $\dfrac{x-2}{2} =\dfrac{y+2}{-4} =\dfrac{z+3}{9}$ contains the point $(3,-4,1)$?

Comment: Did you try plugging in those values?

Comment: Plugging them in where?

Comment: into your line's equation.

Comment: @Tina: $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(3,-4,1)$ do they satisfy the equation(s), ie. $\frac{x_0-2}{2}=\frac{y_0+2}{-4}=\frac{z_0+3}{9}$?

Comment: If I sub in the values for x,y,z the answer is 1/2=1/2=4/9 so that would mean that the point is not on the line wouldn't it?

Comment: A+++++++++++++++

Answer (score 1):

An idea: you may want to write your line's equation in a more *normal* or friendly way:

$$\frac{x-2}2=\frac{y+2}{-4}=\frac{z+3}9\implies18x-36=-9y-18=4z+12\implies$$

$$\begin{cases}-9y=4z+30\implies y=-\dfrac49z-\dfrac{10}3\\{}\\
18x=-9y+18=4z+30+18=4z+48\implies x=\frac29z+\frac83\end{cases}$$

Thus, your line is

$$\left\{\;\left(2t+24\,,\,-4t-30\,,\,9t\right)\;:\;\;t\in\Bbb R\;\right\}=(24\,,\,-30\,,\,0)+t(2\,,\,-4\,,\,9)$$

Well, now just check...and verify the point is **not** on the line.